# How can I root my Sony Xperia u?

Tags: rooting, sony-xperia-u

I have used several one-click methods but none of them worked for me.

Can anyone tell me the correct process?

- Android version: 2.3.7
- model number: st25i
- build number: 6.0.B.3.184

Comment: I've become reluctant to answer this sort of questions here on AE because of how quickly tutorials might become out of date (with device updates and such) and how little continuing support you'll receive for rooting instructions. That being said, [XDA-Developers](http://www.xda-developers.com) has always been my #1 choice for instructions and support for specific devices. Fortunately, XDA does have a very comprehensive tutorial on rooting the [Xperia U](http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Sony_Xperia_U#Root_Xperia_U).

Comment: Use iRoot PC version from Mgyun. The apk version failed but the desktop version works just fine. Tested on ICS.

Comment: You could try Kingroot or Kingoroot. Or some sofware on the PC. I am not sure about Gingerbread though.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've found so far there's no known way for GingerBread (2.3.7) except bootloader unlock, which wipes the storage clean on the phone.  ICS is a different matter.